# How to remove duplicate attr href but keep the first by javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to remove duplicate attr href but keep the first by Javascript or jQuery?

Below is the default code. And `a.class` and `id` can not change.

```
<div class="test-class">
  <a href="test-0" class="link">Text0</a> 
  <a href="test-1" class="link">Text1</a> 
  <a href="test-1" class="link">Text1</a> 
  <a href="test-2" class="link">Text2</a>
  <a href="test-2" class="link">Text2</a>
  <a href="test-3" class="link">Text3</a> 
  <a href="test-3" class="link">Text3</a> 
  <a href="test-3" class="link">Text3</a> 
</div>
```

I need to this:

```
<div class="test-class">
  <a href="test-0" class="link">Text0</a> 
  <a href="test-1" class="link">Text1</a> 
  Text1
  <a href="test-2" class="link">Text2</a>
  Text2
  <a href="test-3" class="link">Text3</a> 
  Text3
  Text3
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would do approximately what you are looking for:

```js
let tracker = {}; // track href values

$('a').each(function(anc) {
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  if (tracker.hasOwnProperty(href)) {
    $(this).replaceWith(`<div>${$(this).text()}</div>`);
  } else {
    tracker[href] = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test-class">
  <a href="test-0" class="link">Text0</a>
  <a href="test-1" class="link">Text1</a>
  <a href="test-1" class="link">Text1</a>
  <a href="test-2" class="link">Text2</a>
  <a href="test-2" class="link">Text2</a>
  <a href="test-3" class="link">Text3</a>
  <a href="test-3" class="link">Text3</a>
  <a href="test-3" class="link">Text3</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below javascript:

```js
var hrefTags = document.getElementsByTagName('A');
var arrValue = [];
for (var i=0; i<hrefTags.length; i++){
  if(arrValue.indexOf(hrefTags[i].innerHTML)>-1){
    hrefTags[i].outerHTML = hrefTags[i].outerHTML.replace(/a/g, 'span');
    i--;
  } else {
    arrValue.push(hrefTags[i].innerHTML);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="test-class">
  <a href="test-0" class="link">Text0</a> 
  <a href="test-1" class="link">Text1</a> 
  <a href="test-1" class="link">Text1</a> 
  <a href="test-2" class="link">Text2</a>
  <a href="test-2" class="link">Text2</a>
  <a href="test-3" class="link">Text3</a> 
  <a href="test-3" class="link">Text3</a> 
  <a href="test-3" class="link">Text3</a> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late response, but this is my answer: :D

```
$(window).on('load',function() {
    var last_elm = $('a[href]:first').text();
    $('a[href]').each(function(i) {
        var content = $(this).text();
        if (i && content==last_elm) $(this).replaceWith('<span>'+content+'</span>');
        last_elm=content;
    });
});
```